# Can you download all google maps data in certain area?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

Knowing the reference point, I want to get a list of all the shops (and co ordinates) based in that area.. For example all the shops in this mall:
https://goo.gl/maps/GFfWx8pze2T2

Is there a tool to do this online or something I can programatically use?

Comment: I want it by lat/long so my phone can react when I enter a store and give me their website.  I can do the programming; just need the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you want to use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/).  It allows you to search by keywords.  You need to provide an API key, but for a free account you can get quite a few requests in per month.

I'm assuming you want to access it with JavaScript?  There is also a nice [Python wrapper for it on GitHub](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places).

What you get back is not a download per se, but it provides all the info you need as JSON so you can easily create shapefiles or whatever format you need.  You can even get at the photos associated with the places.